# How can I check which of my server's ports are open using only CPanel?

Tags: server, cpanel, lamp, port-number, ssh

I have been trying to get SSH access to my shared LAMP server for ages. I suspect that the ports are locked down or different to what they should be. Currently, the only access I have to the server is with CPanel.

Is there a way I can check what ports are open just using CPanel?

Comment: What OS are you using? CentOS, FreeBSD, RHE? To see what ports open, you can run the following command:
/usr/bin/nmap localhost
You can install nmap using this command (assuming you have CentOS or FC):
yum install nmap

Comment: "SSH access to my shared LAMP server" - have you asked your host? Many "shared hosts" don't allow SSH access out of the box; you may need to explicitly request it. Some don't allow it at all. Is SSH access "advertised"? If it is then they should tell you the port number(s). What response do you get? Have you tried a port scanner?

Answer (score 1):

SSH runs on port 22 by default on cPanel & WHM servers, however the port number is often changed to prevent brute force attempts. You'll need to contact your web hosting provider to see which port SSH runs on, and to see if SSH access is enabled on your cPanel account.